# How do make like this slider widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, slider

I have a task,
and i need to build like this slider.
can anyone help me?
[image]

i try use alot of packeges but i didn't get the same result of picture

Comment: Check this Link - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html

Answer (score 1):

api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).